# How to remove items from a generic list after N minutes?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a list as below:

```
private List<DateTime> _result = new List<DateTime();
```

and I add values to it like

```
_result.Add(DateTime.Now);
```

The requirement is that each item which is added should be removed from the list within 5 minutes deadline.

I was thinking I could create a Timer which checks my list every e.g. 1 minute and find old items and remove them but I hoped there could be an easier way?

How to implement it?

Thanks

Comment: Is it important that they are removed exactly on time, or simply that accessors never hand back items older than 5 mins?

Comment: Not very important. It just has to be cleaned up regularly to avoid getting its size huge.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take on this:

```
public class DateWrapper
{
    private ConcurrentBag<DateWrapper> list;
    private DateTime time;

    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return time; }
    }

    private Timer timer;

    public DateWrapper(ConcurrentBag<DateWrapper> _list, DateTime _time)
    {
        list = _list;
        time = _time;

        list.Add(this);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 300000; // 5 Minutes
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

The above work for small list of item. With a too big list, you get too many timer... and performance would get hurt.

So, if you have to handle lot of items, here's a generic way to do it:

```
public class ExpirableList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private volatile List<Tuple<DateTime, T>> collection = new List<Tuple<DateTime,T>>();

    private Timer timer;

    public int Interval
    {
        get { return timer.Interval; }
        set { timer.Interval = value; }
    }

    private TimeSpan expiration;

    public TimeSpan Expiration
    {
        get { return expiration; }
        set { expiration = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Define a list that automaticly remove expired objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_interval"></param>
    /// The interval at which the list test for old objects.
    /// <param name="_expiration"></param>
    /// The TimeSpan an object stay valid inside the list.
    public ExpirableList(int _interval, TimeSpan _expiration)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = _interval;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick);
        timer.Start();

        expiration = _expiration;
    }

    private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - collection[i].Item1) >= expiration)
            {
                collection.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    #region IList Implementation
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return collection[index].Item2; }
        set { collection[index] = new Tuple<DateTime, T>(DateTime.Now, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return collection.Select(x => x.Item2).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return collection.Select(x => x.Item2).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        collection.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, T>(DateTime.Now, item));
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return collection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
            array[i + index] = collection[i].Item2;
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool contained = Contains(item);
        for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if ((object)collection[i].Item2 == (object)item)
                collection.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        return contained;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int i)
    {
        collection.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((object)collection[i].Item2 == (object)item)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        collection.Insert(index, new Tuple<DateTime, T>(DateTime.Now, item));
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((object)collection[i].Item2 == (object)item)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        collection.Clear();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you think this would have any performance issues with tens of thousands of items in the list vs a single thread removing items by checking if they are expired?

Comment: @DaveBish: Thanks. Fixed it. ConcurrentBag instead of List.

Comment: @RichardFriend: Well... Yeah. If you plan to have tens of thousands of items, I would implement it a different way. I had the feeling that if he removes them after 5 mins, he might not plan to add that many.

Comment: @LightStriker I only ask because i am just doing something very similar to expire items in a cache, and this approach crossed my mind... i will continue to observe :)

Comment: @RichardFriend: I edited my answer with a second solution that would be better with large collection of items. Or if you don't want an interface, you could use a `Tuple<DateTime, T>` and let the list add the time itself.

Comment: @RichardFriend: And because I'm an idiot with too much time on his hand, I did just that. Edited my answer with a list that manage the time the item is added to the list by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background thread, which will be iterate through the list and remove unneeded elements.

```
public void RemoveDates()
        {
            var checkDatesTask= new Task(
                () =>
                    {
                        while (!_cancelationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            //TODO: check and delete elements here

                            _cancelationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(
                                   5));
                        }
                    },
                _cancelationTokenSource.Token,
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            checkDatesTask.Start();
        }
```

p.s. I suggest you read more about async. operations.